# Get name if range values are true Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a *pandas* question about getting a name if a range of values is true from an X column. **If year is inside its decade from 1960 until now, print the Name** So here is an example of my dataframe:

```
#,Name,description,year
1,a,foo,1961
2,a,foo2,1977
3,a,foo3,1980
4,a,foo4,1995
5,a,foo5,2001
6,a,foo6,2011
7,a,foo7,2020
8,b,bar,1965
9,b,bar2,1970
10,b,bar3,1983
11,b,bar4,1997
12,b,bar5,2005
13,b,bar6,2016
14,b,bar7,2022
15,c,abc,1965
16,c,ab2,1970
17,c,abc3,1993
18,c,abc4,2007
19,c,abc5,2015
20,c,abc6,2020
```

Output: **a,b**

So far, I did this:

```
dataset[Year].str.match(str(year[0:3]))
```

I think I need a `for` loop for this, but I am not sure at all. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is by creating groups using [Pandas groupby method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
and then filtering the groups using [Pandas filter method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

```
import pandas as pd


def is_within_range(group):
    years = sorted(list(group["Year"]))
    check_decade = {}
    for year in years:
        decade = year // 10
        if 196 <= decade <= 202:
            check_decade[decade] = True
    if len(check_decade.keys()) == (202 - 196 + 1):
        return True
    return False


data = pd.read_csv("years.csv")
filtered_data = data.groupby(['Name']).filter(lambda x: is_within_range(x))
print(list(filtered_data.Name.unique()))
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b']
```

`years.csv`:

```
#,Name,Description,Year
1,a,foo,1961
2,a,foo2,1977
3,a,foo3,1980
4,a,foo4,1995
5,a,foo5,2001
6,a,foo6,2011
7,a,foo7,2020
8,b,bar,1965
9,b,bar2,1970
10,b,bar3,1983
11,b,bar4,1997
12,b,bar5,2005
13,b,bar6,2016
14,b,bar7,2022
15,c,abc,1965
16,c,ab2,1970
17,c,abc3,1993
18,c,abc4,2007
19,c,abc5,2015
20,c,abc6,2020
```

**Explanation:**

- The `is_with_range` method check if a group has years from each decade from 1960 to 2020. Decade of an year is `year // 10`. E.g. year 1965 and the year 1969 have a decade value of 196 while 1996, 1998 have a decade value of 199.
- I used a dictionary to flag each decade to `True` and later on count the number of decades in the group.

**References:**

- [Pandas documentation on dataframe groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)
- [Pandas documentation on dataframe filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dataframe.query method to do the same like dataset.query("year">=1961, inplace=True)
print(dataset) #it replace dataframe with those values whuch has year greater than 1961

Comment: I see your point, but if there is a name that for example there is a decade that has not a year? e.g.(1962,1970,1990,2000,2010,2020). It is missing 1980 and the example years are greater than 1961. Maybe the condition should be: 1960<=year<=1969 && 1970<=year<=1979...?

Comment: It supports conditional expressions as well you can use this query "1960<=year<=1969 && 1970<=year<=1979" to filterout your dataframe.